# Office Online Server Error - HTTP Request Forbidden

Tags: sharepoint-2016, office-online-server

I am attempting to set up PowerPivot in my SharePoint Server 2016 environment. I get to the point of running New-OfficeWebAppsExcelBIServer and receive an error saying that the HTTP request was forbidden. I run other commands on OOS like Get-OfficeWebAppsHost and receive the same issue. There are two errors in the logs below. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
> request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> 
> Server stack trace:     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
> HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
> WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)
> 
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.IFarmStateManagerService.GetBiServerAllowList(DateTime
> lastGetTime, Guid correlationId)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.RemoteFarmAllowList.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.RemoteFarmAllowListWrapper.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.ACacheableFarmStateObject.Sync(Boolean
> force)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.AFarmAllowList.Contains(String
> endpoint)    at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.NewExcelBIServerCommand.ProcessRecordCore()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.AOfficeWebAppsCommand.ProcessRecord()
> 
> Details tab:
> 
> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
> request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack
> trace: at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
> HttpChannelFactory`1 factory) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
> WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.IFarmStateManagerService.GetBiServerAllowList(DateTime
> lastGetTime, Guid correlationId) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.RemoteFarmAllowList.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.RemoteFarmAllowListWrapper.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.ACacheableFarmStateObject.Sync(Boolean
> force) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.AFarmAllowList.Contains(String
> endpoint) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.NewExcelBIServerCommand.ProcessRecordCore()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.AOfficeWebAppsCommand.ProcessRecord()

Second error:

> Error when trying to connect to Farm State Manager service:
> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
> request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack
> trace: at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
> HttpChannelFactory`1 factory) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory,
> WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.IFarmStateManagerService.GetAllSettings(DateTime
> lastGetTime, Guid correlationId) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.RemoteFarmSettings.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.ACacheableFarmStateObject.Sync(Boolean
> force) at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.AFarmSettings.get_MasterMachineName()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.RemoteFarmState.get_IsMaster()
> at Microsoft.Office.Web.WacServer.FarmStateReplicator.Replicate()


The ULS log:

> 12/07/2018 15:42:19.09    PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)            
>   0x27DC  Office Online                   PowerShell Cmdlets           
>   ai18g   Medium      Beginning execution of the
> Get-OfficeWebAppsExcelBIServer cmdlet. Parameters:
>   148aa0af-4451-4a07-9793-434d2c9bd4cd 12/07/2018 15:42:19.10
>   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  Services
> Infrastructure        Office Service Finder           adshj   Medium 
>   ReadAllAgentProperties: [C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Web
> Apps\AgentManager\AgentProperties.xml]    148aa0af-4451-4a07-9793-434d2c9bd4cd
> 12/07/2018 15:42:19.10    PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)            
>   0x27DC  Office Online                   Office Viewing Architecture  
>   ai6rl   Medium      BindingManager.OpenChannel: FarmStateManager
> UREDACTED_(kjZMBVmjgNtgh9z7SPMD5RmEj97y4UQNShcRwCvSuik=)  148aa0af-4451-4a07-9793-434d2c9bd4cd
> 12/07/2018 15:42:19.10    PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)            
>   0x27DC  Office Online                   Office Viewing Architecture  
>   awbfz   Medium      BindingManager.GetBindingForInstance:
> FarmStateManager  148aa0af-4451-4a07-9793-434d2c9bd4cd 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.10   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  Office
> Online                    Office Viewing Architecture     awbf0   Medium 
>   BindingManager.OpenChannel About to
> CreateChannel 148aa0af-4451-4a07-9793-434d2c9bd4cd 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.10   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  Office
> Online                    Office Viewing Architecture     awbf1   Medium 
>   BindingManager.OpenChannel Time to open channel [time: 1.556ms, uri:
> UREDACTED_(kjZMBVmjgNtgh9z7SPMD5RmEj97y4UQNShcRwCvSuik=)] 148aa0af-4451-4a07-9793-434d2c9bd4cd
> 12/07/2018 15:42:19.32    w3wp.exe (0x2ADC)                      
>   0x3408  ULS Logging                     Logging Correlation Data     
>   xmnv    Medium      Name=Task: Memory
> Manager.PerformCleanup    53fed7f1-03f1-0002-9888-cd52a6d4bc07 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.32   w3wp.exe (0x2ADC)                           0x3408  Excel
> Online                    Excel Calculation Services      8jg2    Medium 
>   ResourceManager.PerformCleanup: Memory Manager:
> CurrentSize=220422144.    53fed7f1-03f1-0002-9888-cd52a6d4bc07 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.46   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  Office
> Online                    PowerShell Cmdlets           
>   ai18i   Exception   An unhandled exception was thrown in the Office
> Online Server cmdlets.
> System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: The HTTP
> request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'.
> ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server
> stack trace:      at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest
> request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException,
> HttpChannelFactory`1 factory)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestRepl...  d651d786-82dd-0000-cb20-78d6dd82d401
> 12/07/2018 15:42:19.46*   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)            
>   0x27DC  Office Online                   PowerShell Cmdlets           
>   ai18i   Exception   ...yResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse
> response, HttpChannelFactory`1 factory, WebException
> responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
> timeout)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
> TimeSpan timeout)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
> message, TimeSpan timeout)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
> Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
> Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
> methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at
> System.ServiceMod...  d651d786-82dd-0000-cb20-78d6dd82d401 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.46*  PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  Office
> Online                    PowerShell Cmdlets           
>   ai18i   Exception   ...el.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
> message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
> reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at
> System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
> msgData, Int32 type)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.IFarmStateManagerService.GetAllSettings(DateTime
> lastGetTime, Guid correlationId)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.RemoteFarmSettings.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.RemoteFarmSettingsWrapper.Refresh()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.ACacheableFarmStateObject.Sync(Boolean
> force)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.AFarmSettings.get_MasterMachineName()
> at Micros...  d651d786-82dd-0000-cb20-78d6dd82d401 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.46*  PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  Office
> Online                    PowerShell Cmdlets           
>   ai18i   Exception   ...oft.Office.Web.Apps.Environment.WacServer.RemoteFarmState.get_IsMaster()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.CmdletUtils.TryReplicateFromMaster(IFarmState
> localFarmState)     at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.GetExcelBIServerCommand.ProcessRecordCore()
> at
> Microsoft.Office.Web.Apps.Administration.AOfficeWebAppsCommand.ProcessRecord()
> StackTrace:  at uls.native.dll:
> (sig=93921b0b-1b34-4c76-b38c-fe12f5638234|2|uls.native.pdb,
> offset=29BE5) at uls.native.dll:
> (offset=1F9BE)    d651d786-82dd-0000-cb20-78d6dd82d401 12/07/2018
> 15:42:19.46   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  ULS
> Logging                       Unified Logging Service      
>   c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Uninitialized ULS,
> ULSException14, a354bb5e "office online", 100020ef "16.0.8431.0",
> c180aef3 "mscorlib", 04070c95 "4.7.3221.0", 5b8858c6 "thu aug 30
> 16:51:18 2018", 000056e9 "000056e9", 00000027 "00000027", 7ad57f15
> "messagesecurityexception", 0021b888
> "ai18i"   d651d786-82dd-0000-cb20-78d6dd82d401 12/07/2018 15:42:19.46
>   PowerShell_ISE.exe (0x296C)                 0x27DC  ULS Logging          
>   Unified Logging Service         b6ig    Medium      Data collection is not
> enabled for tag 'ai18i' in the configuration or configuration file not
> available. Not reporting to
> Watson    d651d786-82dd-0000-cb20-78d6dd82d401
```

Comment: I was able to solve my issue. Gave Network Service account permissions to folder with Farm State Manager Service and then restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my issue. Gave Network Service account permissions to folder with Farm State Manager Service and then restarted.